# How programatically get index of a pivot table row and column combined

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

I have pivot table named `SalesBySchools` and pivot field named `Subjects`. I want to sort `Subjects` by `Sum of Cases` in `descending` order using values in this column `2023:January`(By current year, current month).

My pivot table layout looks as shown on the image below.[image]

So Far I have the below code in VBA.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesBySchools").PivotFields("Subjects"). _
    AutoSort xlDescending, "Sum of Cases", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesBySchools" _
    ).PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(6), 1
```

I need to dynamically get that `6` inside `PivotLines()` using the column `2023:January`. How can I do that?